# Problema a la hora de mostrar un json de mi localhost

Tags: android, json, api

estoy desarrollando una `app` en la q quiero conectar dicha `app` a una `api`. Pero estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de recibir el `json` para poder mostrarlo dentro de mi `app`. Comparto el codigo.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText etResponse;
    TextView tvIsConnected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // get reference to the views
        etResponse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResponse);
        tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);

        // check if you are connected or not
        if(isConnected()){
            tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
            tvIsConnected.setText("You are conncted");
        }
        else{
            tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT conncted");
        }

        // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
        new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://localhost/usuario/");
    }

    public static String GET(String url){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }

    public boolean isConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            return GET(urls[0]);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            etResponse.setText(result);

        }
    }
}
```

Activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIsConnected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="is connected? " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etResponse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >\
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

El `json` q intento mostrar en mi `app`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: ¿Está claro que tiene correctamente agregado los permisos ? en manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola el problema que tienes es un tema de direccionamiento IP, [localhost](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) es un nombre reservado que tienen todas las computadoras, ratón o dispositivo independientemente de que disponga o no de una tarjeta de red ethernet. El nombre localhost es traducido como la dirección IP de loopback 127.0.0.1 en IPv4, o como la dirección ::1 en IPv6.1​

En resumen esta linea esta mal la URL

```
new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://localhost/usuario/");
```

A menos que el servidor se este ejecutando del dispositivo. En general para el resto de los dispositivo en una red local la IPv4 de tu equipo suele ser de este estilo `192.168.x.x`, puedes averiguarlo facilmente de la siguiente manera:

Windows, abre `cmd` o `powershell` y escribe:

```
ipconfig
```

Linux

```
ifconfig
```

Con ello te mostraran la IP local de tu PC, un ejemplo en windows

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Direccion IPv4 es la IP de la PC que tendrás que colocar, Puerta de enlace es la IP del router.

Comment: He probado ya reemplazar el `localhost` por mi dirección de `ip` y aun asi no logro obtener el `json`

Comment: Prueba acceder desde el navegador del celular para ver si estas recibiendo los datos, también puedes tener un problema de firewall que el pc te esta bloqueando las peticiones entrantes

Answer (score 1):

Cuando escribes `localhost`, el DNS buscara en la **maquina local** el recurso indicado. Este dispositivo local representa tu dispositivo y lo mas seguro es que el API esta instalado en otra maquina, no en tu smartphone. En otras palabras, cuando buscas en tu dispositivo: `/localhost/usuario/`, se esta intentando conectar a tu propio dispositivo android buscando el recurso `/usuario/`.

Para lograr lo que quieres tienes que indicarle la IP de donde esta instalada el API. Donde esta instalado el api, ejecuta el cmd  y escribe el comando `ipconfig` en la opcion `Wireless Lan Adapter Wifi -> IPv4`:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::611d:8046:c32b:991b%14
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5 <--------- Aqui estaria la IP que reemplazarias por localhost
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Como ya seguro habrás notado, la pc donde tienes instalada el API tiene que estar conectada a la misma red de tu dispositivo, ya se wifi si es con un dispositivo fisico o LAN si es con un emulador, sino el dispositivo android no podra en contrar ese recurso.

Para comprar que estan el misma red, abre el navegador de tu dispositivo y escriba la ip de la maquina donde esta instaldo el api, si la encuentra te mostrar la informacion del IIS/APACHE o cualquier servidor http, de lo contrario tendras que crear una conexion entre ambas.

Comment: He probado ya reemplazar el `localhost` por mi dirección de `ip` y aun asi no logro obtener el `json`

Comment: Estas probando en un dispositivo fisico?

Comment: Testeado en uno físico y en virtual

Comment: Intentaste acceder a al API por el navegador del dispositivo? Que muestra?

Comment: El problema estaba alli no estaba accediendo desde el dispositivo al navegador, ahora pude resolver el problemita